# Weird page loads sometimes in Rails 3.2 could be CSS?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, asset-pipeline

I've only been programming for roughly 20 weeks so every problem I run into is new to me...

I'm not quite sure, but I suspect that sometimes my page loads prior to all my CSS files loading because I'll see the page content for a brief second then suddenly the CSS takes over and presents the page.

Any ideas on what I could possibly do to fix this? If this is a little hard to imagine, my website is http://www.instamap.it

Answer (score 2):

yep, looking at your source, you should move the link for your css to the head in your application layout.

Answer (score 1):

It's because your CSS is being linked at the end of your document instead of the beginning, so the page loads everything else first.

This line (169):

```
<link href="/assets/application-9541dd7ae253c39af6731980dce6e296.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

should be in the head of your document.  This way the CSS will load before everything else.